# 2 Bags Full of Coins

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am having a hard time trying to understand which answer I got is correct. Here is the situation. There are two bags of coins:

Bag1 has 5 Quarters, 4 Dimes, 7 Nickels

Bag2 has 4 Quarters, 6 Dimes, 8 Nickels

I am trying to figure out how many ways I can pull 2 different coins from each bag.

This is the first answer I got for which I pulled from only the first bag and then the second.

```
(5x6)+(5x8)+(4x4)+(4x8)+(7x4)+(7x6)= 188
```

Now if I pull from the first bag, then the second, then I pull from the second and then the first I get this.

```
(188)+(4x4)+(4x7)+(6x5)+(6x7)+(8x5)+(8x4)= 376
```

Which is the correct answer and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods count the same thing and give an answer of $188$. In these problems, it can probably be assumed that order doesn't matter, so you can stop at the first line.

In the second line, you are counting the number of ways if you pull from Bag $1$ and then Bag $2$, plus the number of ways pulling from Bag $2$ and then Bag $1$. This is redundant since the outcomes are the same.

It might make more sense to look at a simpler example: Bag $1$ contains one quarter; Bag $2$ contains one dime. How many ways can we draw two coins such that they are different? Clearly there is only one way, and it seems silly to claim that there are two based on which is drawn first.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer plus example, that makes this a lot more understandable. I will accept this answer when the timer runs up.